# Find (linear) transformation matrix using the fact that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is the first time I post something on this website. I'm on this question already for hours. I'm clearly not asking the community to do my homework, I'm hoping someone can explain me how I should solve the following question;

> Let $l$ be a line through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $P_l$ the linear transformation that projects a vector onto $l$, and $F_l$ the transformation that reflects a vector in $l$.

- Draw diagrams to show that $F_l$ is linear. *Diagrams? How does this look like? A standard matrix?*
- Figure 3.14 (see image) suggests a way to find the matrix of $F_l$, using the fact that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other. Prove that $F_l = 2P_l(x) - x$, and use this result to show that the standard matrix of $F_l$ is (see image).
- If the angle between $l$ and the positive $x$-axis is $A$, show that the matrix of $F_l$ is (see image).

**I attached the question as image**

Hopefully you can help.

Thanks!

Image: i.stack.imgur.com/vFkmM.jpg

*EDIT: Image shown here:*

[image]

Comment: The problem as stated is ambiguous—there are many ways to project a vector onto $\mathscr l$. The illustration and the fact that a reflection is also involved suggests that $P_{\mathscr l}$ is meant to be orthogonal projection.

Comment: The proposed symmetry matrix is clearly an orthogonal one with det = -1 (orientation reversal) ; thus it is a good candidate. It seems to me that you just have to check that a directing vector of line $\ell$ is transformed into itself, and an orthogonal vector to $\ell$ is transformed into its opposite. Concerning the formulas inside the matrix, they come from tangent half angle formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula

Comment: @JeanMarie, thank you for your reply. Still I don't know where to start or what to do? Could you help me a bit more? What exactly would be the answer to such question? (It's just a practice exercise for me.) Sorry if I'm asking too much.

Comment: Could someone please solve this one for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, the diagram which you should draw is similar to the figure 3.14.  Your map $F_\ell : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is *linear* if $F_\ell(x+y) = F_\ell(x) + F_\ell(y)$ and $F_\ell(cx) = cF_\ell(x)$.  Here $x$, $y$ are points in your domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $c$ is a scalar.  You can check the equalities by drawing the vectors on either side of the two equations I wrote.  For example, to check the second equality, you have $x$, $\ell$, and $F_\ell(x)$ already drawn in Figure 3.14.  Try drawing $cx$, then $F_\ell(cx)$, and draw $cF_\ell(x)$, and verify that these latter two are equal.  You can do something similar for the first equality.

For part b: I'd prefer to rewrite the equality as $x + F_\ell(x) = 2P_\ell(x)$.  Now look at Figure 3.14.  How is the left side, $x + F_\ell(x)$, depicted geometrically?  How is $2P_\ell(x)$ depicted geometrically?  Convince yourself that these vectors are equal.

Now the standard matrix of a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ consists of two columns: the first column says what the map does to the vector $\langle 1, 0 \rangle$, and the second column says what the map does to the vector $\langle 0, 1 \rangle$.  You should first write the standard matrix for $P_\ell$ by actually computing the vector projection of each of these two basis vectors onto the vector $\langle d_1, d_2 \rangle$.  Now you can use the equality to compute the standard matrix of $F_\ell$.

Finally, part c will follow from b if you plug in the direction vector $\langle \cos \theta, \sin \theta \rangle$.